# Bootstrap 4 nav-tabs namespace collision: class “show” for nav-item & tab-panes activation?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**a shorter version might be: is `.show` a reserved Bootstrap 4 class name?**

I was having all sorts of problems with my UI after upgrading to Bootstrap 4.0.0 from on alpha-6.  Nav-links were hidden and tab-panes were appearing at the bottom of my screen.

Then I notice that my Vue component had this CSS:

```
.show{
    position: fixed;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 70px;
    color : red;
}
```

which corresponded to my tab-panes appearing in the wrong spot.

And, what I am curious about is inspecting the elements on the navs and tabs I see, in addition to the expected `.active` class, `.show`:

[image]

But I am pretty sure I am not putting it there, so wondering if Bootstrap 4 is now adding `.show` as well as `.active`.  Is this documented anywhere?  If so, I need to avoid a css class name clash, in my case, changing the Vue component's embedded css to `.show2` made my problem go away for now.

And a search for `show` on Bootstrap'd github looks like they do use it:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=show&type=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `.show` class (as well as `.active`) is definitely used by Bootstrap 4 for nav tabs and some other things as well.

From the docs:

> The first tab pane must also have `.show` to make the initial content visible.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#via-javascript

And:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#tabshow